# Javascript recording and repeating touch events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to record and repeating touches programmatically. All my efforts have failed. What is wrong?

```
var elm = null, begin = true, touches = [];

$(document).ready(function () {

    elm = $('#element');

    elm.bind('touchstart touchmove touchend touchcancel', function (e) {
        if (begin) {
            touches.push(e);
            if (e.type == 'touchend') {
                begin = false;
                start();
            }
        }
    });
});


function start() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        try {
            for (var e in touches) elm.dispatchEvent(e);
            // elm.trigger(e.type, e);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
        start();
    }, 5000);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your output? What's your expected output? It looks like you're making an infinite loop since `start()` always calls itself.

Comment: Hi @skyline3000, its true, no output, I want one time touch-swipe from users and caching this event. also repeating infinite without a user action :)